# Kerberos works in IE and Chrome, but doesn't in FF and Safari

Tags: kerberos, single-sign-on

I have a Kerberos secured page, which I can access successfully in IE and Chrome without retyping my user credentials. So the single sign on worked.

With FF a 401 Error page comes directly and with Safari a loginbox comes and when I insert my user credentials it fails and a 401 Error page appears.

I think it works in Chrome because it guesses the SPN right: http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/http-authentication look under Kerberos SPN generation.

**So my Question is:**
Why doesn't it work in FF and Safari, even when login in with the user credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable Negotiate in Firefox `about:config`. Google will help.

Comment: thx.
If other have the problem:
Here is how to: http://grolmsnet.de/kerbtut/firefox.html
And I also had to run "kinit" in the cmd.